# Knn search- after classification how to retrieve the image ? how to find the right value for that index?

Tags: matlab, image-segmentation, knn

i used KNN search for nearest neighbour classification- the size of image is big and i select only 1000 rows-

```
[EG_Training,idx_GS1]=datasample(enhance1_GS_random,1000);
K=33;
[KNN D]= knnsearch(EG_Training, EG_Testing, 'K',K ,'Distance', 'euclidean');**
```

EG_Training is 1000 random rows only- now i have a address(index)of each value in KNN and idx_GS1- my question is how to link these indexes in order to have a segmented image for further evaluation- many thanks

Comment: please do NOT post code in comments - edit your question to reflect what have you tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to convert [linear indices](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#f1-85511) into [row-column indices](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html) you can simply use [`ind2sub`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ind2sub.html):

```
[row col] = ind2sub( size(img), ind );
```

Answer (score 0):

To get back indices into the original signal `enhace1_GS_random`, you can

```
origIdx = idx_GS1( KNN );
```

BTW, using [`datasample`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/datasample.html) you get 1000 samples **with replacement** meaning you might have identical rows in `EG_training`.